# call widget inside cgiGrid view in yii

Tags: gridview, yii, widget

I have custom widget... I just want to call the widget in Tbgridview...

Here is code..

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'id' => 'test1',
'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'name',
    'addr',
    'email',

     array(

                   'type'  => 'raw',
                    'value' => $this->widget('DropDownRedirect', array(
                                 'data' => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3'))),
                 ),
           )
     ));
```

its not working.. can anybody help me?...

please refer the class DropdownRedirect given below.

```
class DropDownRedirect extends CWidget {
public $name; 

public $select; 

public $data; 

public $htmlOptions = array(); 

public $url;

public $replacement = '__value__';

protected function registerScript() {
    $script = '$("#'.$this->id.'").change(function(){'
    .'$(location).attr("href", "'.$this->url.'".replace("'.$this->replacement.'", $(this).val()));'
    .'});';
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(__CLASS__.$this->id, $script);
}

public function init() {
    if (! isset($this->name))
        $this->name= $this->id;
    $this->registerScript();
}

public function run() {
    if (!isset($this->htmlOptions['id'])) $this->htmlOptions['id'] = $this->id;
    echo CHtml::dropDownList($this->name, $this->select, $this->data, $this->htmlOptions);
}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post the class of DropDownRedirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGridView expects a php expression as `value` that results in a string once it is evaluated so

1. the php expression needs to be passed as a string
2. `$captureOutput` (last parameter) of [`CController::widget()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#widget) needs to be set to true in order to capture the widget instead of sending it directly to the display.
3. in the php expression `$this` refers to the [column object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail) so the controller should be referenced using `$this->grid->controller`

Thus:

```
'value' => '$this->grid->controller->widget("DropDownRedirect",
            array("data" => array("1"=>"1","2"=>"2","3"=>"3")),
            true)'
```

Comment: Its show an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\school\framework\base\CComponent.php(606) : eval()'d code on line 1..."

Comment: Does your widget work elsewhere? The `id`,`select` and `url` parameters of your widget do not have default values so it looks like you have to explicitly add those like you did with `data`.

Comment: yes..It works independently ...but when I try to attach with CGI grid view..it doesn't...

Comment: I've updated the answer. I used a similar approach to get a select2 widget into a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
               #'name' => 'name',
               'type'  => 'raw',
                'value' => $this->widget('DropDownRedirect', array(
                             'data' => array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3'))),
             ),
       )
 ));
```

i think you need have a name column.

Comment: "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given"  any idea about this error?